# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable in Sqlite3 with Python script

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this...

```
        cursor.execute("SELECT BoughtPrice FROM Trades ORDER BY IndexNo DESC LIMIT 1")
        connection.commit()
        boughtprice = cursor.fetchone()
        print(boughtprice)
        
       
        boughtprice = cursor[0][0]
        print(boughtprice)
```

I am trying to turn the (0.6655,) result from the SQL query into just 0.6655 by removing the brackets and comma...

Any ideas how I can do that?

Thanks in advance...
I am pulling my hair out!!

Comment: Have you tried with just one [0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Ftagliacarne above...

> Have you tried with just one [0]?

Worked a treat!! :-)